# ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification in java

Tags: java, mysql, oracle11g, syntax-error

I am getting this error-
ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

And this is my block of code-

```
private void updateAttendance(){
    MyQuery mq=new MyQuery();
    Connection con=mq.getConnection();
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;
    try{
        st=con.createStatement();
        rs=st.executeQuery("Select STU_ID FROM STUDENT WHERE NAME='"+cmbName.getSelectedItem()+"'");
        if(rs.next()){
            //System.out.println("getting student name");
            int id=rs.getInt("STU_ID");
            System.out.println(id);
            String sql="UPDATE STUDENT SET CURRENT_DATE='"+lblTime.getText()+"',SUBJECT='"+cmbSub.getSelectedItem()+"',ATTENDANCE=";

            if(rdbtnPresent.isSelected())
                sql+= "'"+Atdnc[0]+"',";
            else
                sql+= "'"+Atdnc[1]+"'";

            sql+="WHERE STU_ID='"+id+"'";
          st.executeUpdate(sql);
            //cmbName.removeAllItems();
        }

    }catch(SQLException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

when I am executing this query(UPDATE STUDENT SET CURRENT_DATE='27TH MAY',SUBJECT='CRYPTOGRAPHY',ATTENDANCE='ABSENT' WHERE STU_ID='40';) in oracle 11g it works fine...but the same sql in eclipse returns error.

Comment: In which `schema` does the table `STUDENT` live in ? say it's school, try to run: `Select STU_ID FROM school.STUDENT WHERE ...`

Comment: I think the problem is in UPDATE query because the select statement gives me the result properly.I mean the id.

Comment: Did you print the query right before executing it and made sure it looks like what you think it looks like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem should be here:

```
if (rdbtnPresent.isSelected())
    sql+= "'"+Atdnc[0]+"',"; // --> this should be "'" as there is no more field
else
    sql+= "'"+Atdnc[1]+"'";
sql+="WHERE STU_ID='"+id+"'"; // --> this should start with a space sql+=" WHERE..
```

So you have 2 issues:

1. If `rdbtnPresent.isSelected()` return `true`, there is a comma that has nothing to do here
2. There is no space before your `WHERE`

`NB:` Consider using `PrepareStatement` instead to avoid this kind of issue, to avoid having to escape your values and to avoid SQL injection attacks.